# Ruby on Rails : Submitted forms wont insert in to SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

Hi
I've come across a weird problem with my application, It wont save to the sqlite DB. When I look at the log it gives me this.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/+...+...=", "product"=>{"title"=>"test", "user_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products"."id" FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."title" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("title", "body", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2011-03-21 09:59:57.546656', '2011-03-21 09:59:57.546656', NULL)
```

This is problaby a newbiefault, but I don't know what to do :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the params hash to your object when you create it like so:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product]
  if @product.save
  # TODO: handle save errors,eg from failed validations etc
  end

  respond_to do |format| 
    format.html # new.html.erb 
    format.xml { render :xml => @product } 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Hi!
I had missed to write ...params[:product].. That was it! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be trying to insert NULL values for all the fields you've created.
The problem must be in the controller file, not the sql code.

You're probably saving an object that doesn't have any properties set.
Are you creating your object with **new** or with **create**? Because if I remmeber correctly **create** takes a hash of parameters and immediately saves the object to the database.
I.e. if you go Myclass.create(), it will fail.

Of course, it would be easier to debug this if you paste your controller code.

Also, are you getting the *product* parameters from params['product'] ?
I.e. params['product']['title'] or params['title']?

Comment: Hi,
This is my code for the production.controller,





  def new
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @product }
    end
  end